# Applications in debug fail to run on device

Tags: xamarin.android

When I try to debug applications on my device, they start and then immediately close. If I deploy them in debug mode, they open and function properly. Applications work properly on the AVDs.

The log file seems to stop after it tries to fire the application.

```
Arguments: -s HT9CSP802883 shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n ActionBarDemo.ActionBarDemo/actionbardemo.Activity1
[STDOUT] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=ActionBarDemo.ActionBarDemo/actionbardemo.Activity1 }
[STDOUT]
```

Does anyone else come across this or ideas on how to get additional debug info?

Comment: Looking at the debug log shows the following error: It should have been installed in the `/home/jon/Development/xamarin/mono/BUILD/armeabi/install/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll' directory. I am not jon, but I am guessing this is an issue with the installer or initial configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is hitting an unhandled exception, check the Android debug log:

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log